# Overload method with spread operator not recognized

Tags: typescript, overloading

I have a class definition as follows:

```
class Test {
  a(msg: string): string;
  a(msg: string, ...args: unknown[]): string | { msg: string, args: unknown[]} {
    if (args) {
      return { msg: msg, args: args };
    }
    return msg;
  }
}
```

However, I get compilation errors if I do this:

```
new Test().a("test", "a", 1, 2, 3);
```

> "Expected 1 arguments, but got 5"

How can I properly overload this method to provide different return types for the different signatures?

Comment: If you want overloads to work, you'll need to provide the same amount of parameters to all functions, for your behavior, it is probably better to choose a different function name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function implementation is not part of all available overloads. Instead you can write:

```
class Test {
    a(msg: string): string; // overload 1
    a(msg: string, ...args: unknown[]): { msg: string, args: unknown[] } // overload2
    a(msg: string, ...args: unknown[]): string | { msg: string, args: unknown[] } { // impl
       // ...
    }
}
```

```
new Test().a("test", "a", 1, 2, 3); // { msg: string; args: unknown[]; }
new Test().a("test") // string
```

[Playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoaXpgBQFsIBzALmmQCcBLAOyIEozLaiBuTbPQ08paugDTQAdKLAUiEMgFcaAaxoB7AO40A2gF1GaaNyZ8WQ8ZJnylqzdAC+HLF2L7+RIaOHGp0WQpXqtjltAAPjp6vE5GEh5e5r7WaLbYWFQAZtC47vTxidnYFPBI0hQ0IQ66xBEmOJHW7DlYNnXQeQVFZWwJNjboNPDKcIhIuPRuuABESAOjQqNgU9AAjEIATEIAzPSs0AD0WyU8zHSb7qbeFhqbNj19CMhDI+OTmTthLEA)

Comment: Thanks for this alternative.  This intrigues me as the documentation states that `overloading with different number of parameters and types with same name is not supported`.  How does this work with overload 1 and overload 2 being different number of parameters?

Comment: If you mean the link from other answer: Honestly, the documentation author doesn't do a good job explaining function overloads in TS and confuses implementation with types side. Just stick to the [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) - they don't state this. Function overloads are a TS feature and can have varying number of parameters, as you have seen. It is just important, that the function implementation signature is compatible to all overloads. You cannot implement a function with same name more than once.

Comment: btw: same principles apply for methods, like in above sample.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript does not support function overloading with different number of parameters.

[Documentation](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/function-overloading) says:

> TypeScript provides the concept of function overloading. You can have multiple functions with the same name but different parameter types and return type. However, the number of parameters should be the same.
>   [...] Function overloading with different number of parameters and types with same name is not supported.

One trick to achieve what you are trying could be this

```
interface ReturnA {
    msg: string;
    args: any[];
}

class Test {

  a(msg: string, ...args: never[]): string;
  a(msg: string, ...args: any[]): ReturnA
  a(msg: string, ...args: any[]): string | ReturnA {
    if (args) return { msg, args };
    return msg;
  }

}

const t = new Test();

// only 1 param returns string
const str: string = t.a(`a`); 

// two or more params returns the other object type
const obj: ReturnA = t.a(`a`, `param1`);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, not sure how I missed that in the docs!

Comment: I think you could try using the `never` params type to hack your example

Comment: Interesting hack!  The output is certainly what I'm looking for.